# BeautifulSoup is not returning the full HTML of the website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website called Autochek for all of their listed cars for sale. Having made the soup, I then create two sub-lists of the soup to iterate through to get the information that I need to then put into a DataFrame but for some reason the Soup is only returning the first 8 vehicles. I think that it's something to do with having to scroll the page to load the data but I'm not sure. Can you help at all?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver # conda install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


url = 'https://autochek.africa/ng/cars-for-sale'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
xpath_search = r'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div'
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_search)
element.click()
element_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/li[4]')
element_2.click()
time.sleep(10)
new_url = driver.current_url
print(new_url)

headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit\
/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'})

url = new_url

response = get(url, headers= headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

tag = 'div'
attributes =  {'class':'car-grid-container'}

content_list = soup.find_all(tag, attributes)

basic_info = []
for item in content_list:
    basic_info.append(item.find_all('a', {'class':'hover:tw-shadow-md'}))

text_info = []
for item in content_list:
    text_info.append(item.find_all('div', {'class':'other-details tw-flex tw-flex-row tw-justify-between tw-items-stretch'}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scroll down to the bottom of the page for all containers (100) to be reachable. You can use the function below to scroll down each time new content is downloaded:

```py
def scroll_down(driver):
        get_scroll_height_command = ("return (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollHeight;")
        scroll_to_command = "scrollTo(0, {});"
        
        # Set y origin and grab the initial scroll height
        y_position = 0
        scroll_height = driver.execute_script(get_scroll_height_command)
        
        while y_position != scroll_height:
            y_position = scroll_height
            driver.execute_script(scroll_to_command.format(scroll_height))
            
            # Page needs to load yet again otherwise the scroll height matches the y position
            # and it breaks out of the loop
            time.sleep(4)
            scroll_height = driver.execute_script(get_scroll_height_command)
```

Where to use:

```py
time.sleep(10)
scroll_down(driver)
new_url = driver.current_url
```

Comment: Thanks, that's scrolling down to the bottom of the page but my scrapes are still just bringing back the first 8 containers. Do I need to indent my soup to make it work, or should it just be working as it is?

Answer (score 0):

No need for Selenium here. Get the data directly from the source:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url ='https://autochek.africa/_next/data/78f0e3518ea1a34c27af75e4181bc80d2c112ebf/ng/cars-for-sale.json'

pageSize = 9999
page = 0

rows = []
for page in range(1,100):
    if page > pageSize:
        break
    print(page)
    payload = {
        'country': 'ng',
        'page_number': '%s' %page}
    
    jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    pageSize = jsonData['pageProps']['pagination']['pageSize']
    
    rows += jsonData['pageProps']['cars']

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
            id                 title  ... hasCleanTitle  soldDate
0    -e4h58sQe          Toyota Camry  ...          True       NaN
1    SWbyrtv5P          Toyota Venza  ...         False       NaN
2    R9_sIKnJy     Toyota Highlander  ...           NaN       NaN
3    4DAiUe1oC          Toyota Camry  ...          True       NaN
4    ECIkVk1aJ          Toyota Camry  ...          True       NaN
..         ...                   ...  ...           ...       ...
571  l7fFI5Q3w          Toyota Camry  ...          True       NaN
572  GquAWYVWu          Toyota Camry  ...          True       NaN
573  SVkuXCLiV         Toyota Matrix  ...           NaN       NaN
574  2O0OKpL_d        Toyota Corolla  ...          True       NaN
575  lp2PtU1oO  Mercedes-Benz ML 350  ...           NaN       NaN

[576 rows x 24 columns]
```